# How many Dragon Shield perfect fit sealable double sleeved cards can fit in a Boulder 100+ Deck Case?

Tags: game-accessories

I've been using a [Quiver Card Case](https://quivertime.com/card-cases/quiver-card-case/) and I've been looking for a deck box that fits inside while holding my double sleeved cards. I'm considering purchasing a [Ultimate Guard Boulder 100+ Deck Case](https://ultimateguard.com/en/boulder/boulder-100-deck-case) to store my double sleeved cards in. The product description says:

> Designed for 100 double-sleeved or 120 single-sleeved standard sized cards
> Inner Dimensions: 68.5 x 67.5 x 93 mm

However, I've been double sleeving my cards with [Dragon Shield Perfect Fit Sealable inner sleeves](https://www.dragonshield.com/webshop/solid-color-sleeves/143-dragon-shield-perfect-fit-sealable-clear.html) to *really* protect my expensive cards. These inner sleeves have a design where the sleeves fold in on themselves to seal the card inside the inner sleeve. This makes the thickness of the inner sleeve one extra layer thick.

Since I don't have the product on hand, I'm unable to test exactly how many of my double sleeved cards might fit inside the deck box.

These cards are for Magic: the Gathering, so typical deck sizes are 100 cards or 75 cards. I don't think I'll be able to fit in the 100 cards, but might I still be able to fit the 75 cards inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a double Sleeved deck with dragon shield resealable inner sleeves and Katana outer Sleeves will just fit into a boulder 100+ (air completly pushed out, difficult in the beginning, but once put in the boulder some timme, no air will go back in ;-))

On some boulder the plastic is slightly warped inwards.
On those you will need to pull outwards with some force but then your deck will fit.
Different thing you can do is put 98 cards in in the desired direction as shown on the product photos online and put the 2 missing cards in 90° rotated (see picture)
[image: Dragonshield resealable inner + UG Katana outer]

For something like KMC perfect fit, they will fit the boulder 0 problems.

Answer (score 1):

If I try to measure my decks that are double sleeved and squish them really tight to get all of the air out, I get these approximate measurements:

| Number of Cards in Deck | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 73mm |
| 90 | 67mm |
| 75 | 55mm |

It seems like a 75 card deck will easily fit within the 67.5mm size of the boulder case, but a 100 card deck is definitely too big. With my rough estimations, I can fit approximately 90 of these kinds of double sleeved cards inside a deckbox, which is under what I was hoping for.

These measurements were done imperfectly with a ruler, but provide a reasonable approximation.